# IntelliJ IDEA generate class file with major version 46

Tags: intellij-idea, javacard

I want to use IntelliJ IDEA for JavaCard 2.2.1 development. The javacard converter requires the class file major version to be 46.

So my question is how can I set class files compatibiliy to 1.2 (which will generate class files with major version 46)?

Here are the class file versions for your reference:

```
Major  Minor Java platform version 
45       3           1.0
45       3           1.1
46       0           1.2
47       0           1.3
48       0           1.4
49       0           1.5
50       0           1.6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File > Setting > Compiler > Java Compiler ... and choose 1.2
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know there are some project-specific settings there.